# OpenCV DroidCam

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera

With my previous laptop (Windows7) I was connecting to my phone camera via DroidCam and using videoCapture in OpenCV with Visual Studio, and there was no problem. But now I have a laptop with Windows 10, and when I connect the same way it shows orange screen all the time. Actually DroidCam app in my laptop works fine, it shows the recording. However while using OpenCV videoCapture from Visual Studio it shows orange screen.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It does not matter whether connecting via usb or wireless.

Comment: It is also the same with Matlab snaphot. Orange screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution from the internet, and while searching found lots of people complaining about that. You disable the camera of your laptop from device manager and then restart. It is working then.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug from the DroidCam app taking over the main source.

**Follow these steps:**

1. Press "Win" key
2. Type "Device Manager"
3. Unfold "Sound, video and game controllers"
4. Right-click DroidCam Source 3 or similar
5. Click on "Disable device"
6. Repeat step 4
7. Click on "Enable device"

This is a solution that worked for me. Let me know if it does it for you. Note that "re-enabling" DroidCam may result in the same problem again.